# redis hvals: get return as array structure

Tags: redis

When I do

```
redis -h host -a password -p port HVALS myhash
```

command on redis, it will return all values of that hash, one per line. In my case that values are JSON formatted strings.

I want to store that return on shell variable and after that use in loop. That strings are separated with spaces by default.

I can treat all questions to avoid any problem to use this variable with loop structure, but I wonder if redis has some way to return a array of strings structure with redis command.

To give an idea about what I am looking for, think something similar or same result as this command:

```
redis -h host -a password -p port HVALS myhash | jq -s
```

In this case jq will work nice because it will recognize JSON objects and will create a array of arrays.

I want to know if is possible to get any array structure of values using only redis, and does not matter if final result is not a valid JSON (forget the fact my strings are JSON strings). And I want only use redis to do this. I can do at shell scripting side, but is not the question.

Comment: You want to use LISTS, done it recently and it works pretty well.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro can you give an example or referer some page? I only found this https://redis.io/topics/data-types

Answer (score 1):

If command `redis -h host -a password -p port HVALS myhash` can return result as each entry separated by `<space>` then you can use arrays.

```
hash_array=($(redis -h host -a password -p port HVALS myhash))
```

and then you iterate with `for` loop

```
for item in "${hash_array[@]}"
do
echo "$item"
done
```

Comment: sure, but I want that from redis and not as a shell script.

Comment: RESP Arrays, https://redis.io/topics/protocol#array-reply.. They written like it can `Similarly certain Redis commands returning collections of elements to the client use RESP Arrays are reply type`.